# Is there a way to have a menu item that brings up a profile that lists a group of people in bulk edit mode?

Tags: profile

I'm trying to simplify a bulk editing via profile for some non savvy users.

The current method is to query up all the contacts in group, select them all, select Batch Update via Prole, then select the profile.  Then you get a list of everyone in the group with the selected profile and the ability to change things without having to open each contact's record.

For some users, this is too many steps.

I'd like to be able to have a menu item that just takes them to the final step.

civicrm 4.6.26 Drupal

Comment: How do you want to pass the criteria for contacts selection?

Comment: Well, I'm open to suggestions but I was thinking all the people in a group.

Comment: Sorry, after a second glance at the core code, I don't think it's possible without writing extension code. I only see batch update fujnctionality in advanced search which needs a valid cache-key. Maybe it's possible to fake an advanced search in an extension and link to batch update page. A general extension allowing to call batch update with group id param would be beneficous for many civi users I think.